# Why does my local webpage behave differently every other time when opened through a AutoHotKey shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, autohotkey

Here's the setup:

I have a test.html file hosted on http://127.0.0.1/test.html. I have a bookmark to that URL in my Firefox browser. I can left-click or middle-click it any number of times to open as many tabs as I want of it, and it always focuses the one and only form element on the page.

The form element has an "autofocus" attribute. No JavaScript is being executed on the page that in any way focuses something else or anything like that.

***The problem:*** To save a lot of time every day (since I open this page perhaps 10,000 times a normal day), I have made an AutoHotKey shortcut to open it with the F1 button:

```
F1::
Run, "http://127.0.0.1/test.html"
return
```

This works, kinda. Every time I press F1, it does open the test.html page in Firefox, just as if I press the bookmark in Firefox. ***However***, unlike the in-browser clicks, this F1 shortcut method apparently does ***something*** differently, because on ***every other*** page load, it does ***not*** focus the one and only form element, as if the "autofocus" attribute doesn't exist.

This has me absolutely baffled. It literally appears to happen ***every other*** time I press F1. Focused, not focused, focused, not focused... No matter how long or short the interval/pause is between each keypress.

Again, it consistently focuses the form element every time I click the bookmark link.

What could possibly be causing this? I can't tell you how much I ***hate*** this kind of nonsense, which seems to always happen no matter what I try to do. It's as if I'm being punished for wanting to be efficient...

Comment: Does pressing F5 return the right focus?

Comment: Test various approaches to isolate the issue: disable Firefox extensions, use a different shortcut key, have AutoHotKey open the shortcut rather than URL, use Javascript to focus instead, etc. *Edit your question to include what you tried*